# Touch pad writer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, events, touch

I need to develop Touch pad writer in iPhone (user will move his finger to  write a letter). I know this is possible, but dont know from where to start. Do I need to use any specific framework or can be done using controls available in Interface Builder.

Please suggest, what will be best approach to achieve this.

Thanks
SD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this sample from apple
https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLPaint/